# Дан двумерный массив размера N×N, заполненный двузначными целыми числами. Требуется вывести все элементы, находящиеся ниже побочной диагонали

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  //Ввод переменных-----------------------------------------------------
  int n, m;
  int a[500][500];
  cin >> n;
  //Ввод массива-----------------------------------------------------
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ; j++) {
      cin >> a[i][j];
    }
  }
  //Вывод элементов ниже побочной диагонали-----------------------------------------------------
  for (int i = 1; i <= n-1; i++) {
      cout << a[i+1][n-1-i] << " "; 
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Код не выводит только последний элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это должно вывести элементы ниже побочной диагонали:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i + j >= n) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " "; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас попробую

Comment: Да, всё сработало, ещё раз спасибо

Comment: @ДаниилШаронов, пожалуйста :)

Comment: думаю пропустили условие   *i != j && i + j >= n*

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, думаю, всё правильно, пример с 5x5 https://onlinegdb.com/Z7Y59-YPI и 4x4 https://onlinegdb.com/gyZl3Ws9b

Comment: Да, все верно, так и должно быть. Я  не учел что на побочной диагонали i != j